# Trying use typescript library with custom tslint rules but got "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error when ng lint

Tags: angular, typescript, shared-libraries, tslint

In my ng-app, package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
...
"@repo/tslint-custom": "0.8.0-dev.23",
...
},
"devDependencies": {
...
"codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
...
}
```

in my tslint-custom library, package.json :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.7",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0"
  }
```

in my ng-app, i have node_modules with tslint-custom/dist/out-tsc/ and inside :

```
- index.d.ts
- index.js
- templateAriaLabelButtonRule.d.ts
- templateAriaLabelButtonRule.js
```

All is good and I have tslint.json like this

```
...        
"template-aria-label-button": true
    },
    "rulesDirectory": [
        "codelyzer",
        "@repo/tslint-custom"
    ]
```

but when I run : ng lint, I have this error :

```
 Linting "ng-app"...
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and in log :

```
[error] /home/myname/ng-app/node_modules/@repo/tslint-custom/dist/out-tsc/templateAriaLabelButtonRule.js:1
import { sprintf } from 'sprintf-js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    ...
```

I tried hard but I don't understand what is wrong...

Could somebody help me please?

Thanks